# Postgresql Ubuntu strange behaviour (version incompatibility?)

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pgadmin, postgresql-9.5, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to run a postgresql Database on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

First I installed postgres using `sudo apt-get install postgresql` which installed version 9.5.1. I then created another user and a new database. I've granted all privileges for the new database to new new user and set the owner to the new user also.

I connected to the new database and filled it by restoring an plain backup (dump) I've created from another database (which has postgresql version 9.2) by using `\i /path/to/dump.sql`. I got no errors, and when I then typen `\dt` I got the list with the tables.

The problem is: When I now disconnect (`\q`) and re-connect (same as I connected before, `sudo psql -U "username" dbname`) and type `\dt` again, it says "No relations found". When I try to fill it again, I get a bunch of errors like "Relation relationname already exists".

Another problem/symptom appears when I try to use pgAdmin (installed via `sudo apt-get install pgadmin3`). When trying to connect using localhost, I can't connect using the newly created user (which which I can connect from the terminal). *But I can* connect using postgres *with the password I set* via Terminal. *I do not see any DB I manually create from command line from pgAdmin tho*.

So yeah, my guess is that at least one problem may be version incompatibility between 9.2 and 9.5. Is there any way to test/fix this? But I also think there should be other problems.

Comment: my guess, but did you try to do dump on 9.2 from 9.5 server? When I migrate to newer version , I usually always dump it remotely on then newer server.

Comment: The other way round. I have a running 9.2 db which I backuped using plain dump. I'm trying to restore this dump to 9.5.

Comment: bad english, I mean call dump script(in which you set the source database and server of 9.2 version) on the 9.5 machine using 9.5 version of PG_DUMP, and then restore it.

Comment: @e4c5 do I have to commit when working from the Ubuntu terminal and being connected to a database? I just tried to type "commit;" after a few changes and it says "Warning: there is no transaction in progress"

Comment: No I meant the commit after the import. I must confess that I have never used \i to load a database dump, but since the dump is in a transaction, I thought it wasn't being committed. Certainly the error you are having is typical of an uncommited transaction.

Comment: I tried the same with "psql -U username -f backup.sql dbname" with the same result :/ Everything appeared fine, I got a bunch of CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE msgs. But when I connected to the database, it again shows "No relatiosn found".

Comment: What are the schemas in the database? Do `\dn` at the psql prompt and once found `\d my_schema.*`

Comment: well how about just using pg_restore http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/app-pgrestore.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe may happen if the SQL dump contains a `SET search_path TO...`command that sets it to a different value than what your user has by default.

So not only it will create its tables and other objects in that schema, but it will leave that `search_path` for the rest of the session, so when you do `\dt` in that same session, it does see and list the newly created tables.

But when you quit and reenter psql, this `search_path` is not longer in effect, you're back to the default `search_path` of your user, which supposedly doesn't reach the schema, so `\dt` no longer "sees" any table.

You can use `show search_path` to check this setting in a psql session, and grep "SET search_path" in the SQL file to check what it's being set to.

---

Per comment, it appears to be the case: the dump creates the tables into a schema that is outside of the user's default search path.

A possible solution for that user to work seamlessly would be to update its search path so that it always reaches this schema first. This can be done with:

```
ALTER USER username SET search_path TO schema1,"$user",public;
```

where `schema1` is what the SQL dump refers to and where it created the tables.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. I've actually found a search_path command in the dump. I also checked the "show search_path" directly after filling the DB from the dump. At this point it was set to the value in the dump ("somestring", pg_catalog). Then I disconnected and connected again and now it shows as "$user", public. May you tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Hey, so I've set the search_path to the database to what is set in the dump and now pgadmin shows the table :) thanks!

Comment: @JacobS: I was just suggesting to do it at the user level in my edit, but that works too at the database level.